# How to get WebView to ignore css

Tags: android, css, webview

I am trying to load a local HTML page in an Android Webview. This page contains some layouting using CSS. But I also noticed that the Webview has a setBackgroundColor() method in which you can set a background color. however this does not work when the CSS file also set a background color.

Does anyone know how to make the Android Webview to ignore these CSS style when I set my own background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add style to your page with javascript:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.background = color;");
```

Call this after you have loaded your url or html.

PS I think if you ignored the CSS you would the get the default white background even if you set setBackGroundColor()

setBackGroundColor is a method that all Views have, that's the only reason WebView has it imo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ePeace. If I try this, then my url is replaced with a blank page containing the color in the style: in this case #fff

Comment: You could try using javascript:
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.background = color;");

Comment: This indeed solves my problem. Can you please edit your answer so I can accept it... thanks